# how to give input to session of putty login using .cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a .cmd file to open a number of putty logins.

How to give my user name and password as input to the opened sessions from .cmd file?

cmd script

START ""  "C:\Documents and Settings\dbteam\Desktop\putty.exe" "192.168.x.xxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated in the putty [manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)

use -l for login name and -pw for the password. e.g.

```
putty.exe -l user -pw passw0rd hostname
```

or the user@hostname syntax:

```
putty.exe -pw passw0rd user@hostname
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also tell me how to input some more commands to the opened putty session. say like after opening the session i would give some commands for all the sessions.

Comment: you can do that with plink.exe (its included in the full putty download), syntax is similar to putty but you can specify commands to execute via command line or a text file. e.g.: plink.exe -l user -pw passw0rd hostname -m yourCommands.txt

Comment: After reading the putty manual i had set the path for plink.exe . When i hit enter it responded(like new cmd prompt). when i gave command it responded " not recognized as internal or external command". What could be the problem.

Comment: just use the full path in your like you do with putty.exe. e.g. "C:\Documents and Settings\dbteam\Desktop\plink.exe". setting the path like described in the putty manual is a bit overkill

Answer (score 1):

load session and auto login with username and password:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -load "session" -l <username> -pw <password>
```

Comment: When opening multiple putty windows in a batch file, the syntax that worked for me was this one: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/615 (remove the word "rem" from each line)